# Why is lean 4 behaving differently on my machine vs in the natural number game?

Tags: lean4, beginner

In the lean 4 version of the natural number game at https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/leanprover-community/NNG4/ , I can use tactics like `apply x at h` and `induction b with d hd`.

In my local copy of lean, which I believe is v4.4.0-rc1, these things cause errors. For example, induction fails when given a `with d hd` suffix:

```
theorem lt_implies_le (a b : Nat)
  (h: a < b)
  : a <= b
  := by
    induction b with d hd  -- "unknown tactic"
```

and `apply` fails when given an `at h` suffix:

```
theorem lt_implies_le (a b : Nat)
  (h: a < b)
  : a <= b
  := by
    induction b
    trivial
    induction a
    simp
    apply Nat.succ_le_succ
    apply Nat.succ_le_succ at h  -- unexpected token 'at'; expected command
```

What is going on? Why is it behaving differently?

Comment: Perhaps you need to import Mathlib?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Why would importing Mathlib change the availability of syntax like an "at" clause on apply?

Comment: Because it's defined in Mathlib. Lean's syntax is extendible.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais This does seem to be the problem. Definitely very confusing. Especially because the natural number game doesn't include the import in its example code.

Comment: I think NNG automatically includes Mathlib in the background.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install Mathlib and then import it with `import Mathlib`.

Also you need to use `induction'` instead of `induction` to get the equivalent behavior to the natural number game.

With Mathlib installed, this example from the game works with an import:

```
import Mathlib

example
  (x y : ℕ)
  (h1 : x = 37)
  (h2 : x = 37 → y = 42)
  : y = 42 := by
  apply h2 at h1
  exact h1
```

and it doesn't work without the import:

```
example
  (x y : ℕ)
  (h1 : x = 37)          -- failed to synthesize instance
  (h2 : x = 37 → y = 42) -- failed to synthesize instance
  : y = 42 := by         -- failed to synthesize instance
  apply h2 at h1         -- unexpected token 'at'
  exact h1
```