# What do I need to import from MathLib to make `induction a with d hd` work?

Tags: lean4, beginner

I know that I need to `import Mathlib` to make `rewrite [x] at h` work. But `induction a with d hd` still doesn't work with just `import Mathlib`. This syntax does work in the natural number game, so I know it's possible to make it work.

What do I need to import to make this example work?

```
import Mathlib

theorem zero_add (n : ℕ) : 0 + n = n := by
induction n with d hd  -- ERROR: unknown tactic
rw [add_zero]
rfl
rw [add_succ]
rw [hd]
rfl
```

In fact, what are *all* the imports used by the natural number game?

*(Note: this is a follow-up to [Why is lean 4 behaving differently on my machine vs in the natural number game?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/why-is-lean-4-behaving-differently-on-my-machine-vs-in-the-natural-number-game)). It would also be acceptable to edit the answer there to include all the imports needed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think currently in Mathlib that version is called `induction'` not `induction`.
So the full command is `induction' n with d hd`.  You can import it with `import Mathlib.Tactic` or just `import Mathlib`.

I think the reason there is a separate `induction'` tactic is because Lean 4 changed the syntax of `induction`.  To be able to still use the old syntax, `Mathlib` added `induction'`.  This made it easier to translate the old Lean 3 proofs.  (And maybe the users like the  `induction'` syntax better.  I don't know.)  If you want to use the new `induction` tactic, you can write:

```
theorem zero_add (n : Nat) : 0 + n = n := by
induction n with
| zero => 
  rw [Nat.add_zero]
| succ d hd =>
  rw [Nat.add_succ]
  rw [hd]
```

This is arguably more general and easier to work with arbitrarily complicated inductive structures.

(As for why it is different in the [Natural Number Game](https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/hhu-adam/NNG4), I think the Natural Number Game is a slight approximation of Lean + Mathlib, or at least it was for the Lean 3 version.  They probably thought it was less confusing to rename `induction'` back to `induction`.  Also, note how the Natural Number Game's `rw` is closer to `rewrite`.  In Lean 4, `rw` automatically tries `rfl` at the end, but `rewrite` doesn't.)

Comment: The NNG authors should at least add a note or something specifying how the syntax of actual Lean is different.  Otherwise, you get this situation where users want to jump into actual Lean code but can't.  The OP should bug Kevin Buzzard about this. :)

Comment: Yeah it's definitely very confusing to play a game specifically to learn lean, and then it sets a series of traps that mean what you learn is different from actually using lean.

Comment: @CraigGidney See the discussion here: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/NNG.20syntax.20different.20from.20Lean.27s